# How does the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials imply that this number is rational?

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

In the *Problems from the Book* by Titu Andreescu, there is a proof of Example 9 on page 494 with the following:

> Example 9. Let $f$ be a monic polynomial with integer coefficients and let $p$ be a prime number. If $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\sqrt[p]{(-1)^{\deg f}f(0)}$ is irrational, then $f(X^p)$ is also irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

> **Solution.** Consider $\alpha$ a complex zero of $f$ and let $n=\deg f$ and $g(X)=X^p$ and $h=g-\alpha$. Using previous results, it suffices to prove that $h$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha][X]$. Because $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, it suffices to prove that $\alpha$ is not the $p-th$ power of an element of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$. Suppose there is $u\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree at most $n-1$ such that $\alpha=u^p(\alpha)$ . Let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_n$ be the zeroes of $f$. Because $f$ is irreducible and $\alpha$ is one of its zeroes, $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, so $f$ must divide $u^p(X)-X$. Therefore $\alpha_1\cdot\alpha_2\cdots\alpha_n=(u(\alpha_1)\cdot u(\alpha_2)\cdots u(\alpha_n))^p.$ **Finally, using the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials, $u(\alpha_1)\cdot u(\alpha_2)\cdots u(\alpha_n)$ is rational.** But $\alpha_1\cdot \alpha_2\cdots \alpha_n=(-1)^nf(0)$, implies $\sqrt[p]{(-1)^nf(0)} \in \mathbb{Q}$, a contradiction.

My question is how does the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials imply that $u(\alpha_1)\cdot u(\alpha_2)\cdots u(\alpha_n)$ is rational?

[The theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials) says that any symmetrical polynomial can be uniquely expressed as a polynomial in elementary symmetric polynomials (one formulation is here [The Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689013/the-fundamental-theorem-of-symmetric-polynomials)), but how does that apply in this case and leads to rationality?

Comment: What do you mean by $u^p(\alpha)$?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain just the power $u^p(\alpha)=(u(\alpha))^p$

Comment: What is $f{}{}{}$?

Comment: Should $f$ be $u$?

Comment: @markvs No, $f \ne u$.

Comment: I guess $f$ is irriducible of $\mathbb Q$, right?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain That's correct (updated in the post), I am thinking I should have maybe included whole statement and the proof, though I am really asking just about the one sentence, the context here is quite expanding :)

Comment: $f$ is not defined in the Q and appears from nowhere. looks like the degree of $f$ is $n$ and it looks like $\alpha$ is its root.

Comment: If $f$  has rational coefficients, then by Vieta theorem, all the elementary symmetric  functions applied to roots of $f$ give rational numbers. Then by the fund. theorem, all symmetric polynomial functions with rational coeffs applied to roots give rational numbers. The function $x_1x_2...x_n$ is symmetric.

Comment: The polynomial $f$ is **not** defined in the post. In fact even that $f$ is a polynomial is only my guess.

Comment: Isn't the solution a bit misleading? To get that $u(\alpha_1)\cdots u(\alpha_n) \in \mathbb Q$ you only need to know that $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are the roots of a polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$, right?

Comment: That's what I am thinking right now, the $\alpha_1\cdot\alpha_2\cdots\alpha_n=(u(\alpha_1)\cdot u(\alpha_2)\cdots u(\alpha_n))^p$ seems to be a bit out of order in the proof, that's what confused me, I was trying to find some connection with this identity...

Comment: To show that $u(\alpha_1)\cdots u(\alpha_n) \in \mathbb Q$ you don't need symmetric polynomials at all. Simply take a field homomorphism and apply it to $u(\alpha_1)\cdots u(\alpha_n)$ and realize that it is fixed because it only permutes the $\alpha_i$.